# tail -f did not continue output the new lines added using vi

Tags: unix, command

When I invoked "tail -f myfile.txt", the new line added using the following command output the new line, but not the line added/saved using vi. Does anyone know why ?

$echo "this is new line" >> myfile.txt

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It has something to do w/the fact that while you are editing the file, `vi` keeps your changes in a second file (`.myfile.txt.swp` in this case).

When you save the changes, it's likely that `vi` is replacing the original file w/the second file. This means the file that `tail` was watching is no longer valid.

To prove this, try your `echo` command after saving the file with `vi`. When you do that, the output won't be displayed by `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

The tail program opens a file, seeks to the end, and (with "-f") waits, then checks again if that open file has anything new to read.

vi does not append to a file. It makes a copy, (not a "swap", which is something else altogether) writes it out, and then moves the new file to have the same name as the old file.

tail is still watching the old file, not looking up a file by that file name every time.

In addition, tail uses the location in the file, so if you delete 10 characters and add 15, the next loop of 'tail' will emit the next 5 it thinks are new because they are after its placeholder.

Run 'tail --follow=name ...' to get tail to look up the file every loop by name, instead of watching the location on disk of a file it opens at start.